# Find the percent increase of the highest bid over the initial amount?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select top 7 item_name, item_reserve, count(bid_id) as bid_count, 
max(bid_amount) as highest_bid, 
item_reserve / max(bid_amount) * 100 as pct_increase
from vb_items
join vb_bids on item_id=bid_item_id
where item_sold = 0 
group by item_name, item_reserve
order by bid_count desc
```

I want to find the percent increase from item_reserve to highest_bid. I think this is more or less correct, but math is not exactly my strong point.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the other way around?  `max(bid_amount)/item_reserve)`?

Comment: Isn't this just a simple math question?

Comment: It is math, but does need to be done in the context of SQL - and some math either can't be done or is harder to be done therein.

Comment: I don't agree with you. Just replace `max(bid_amount)` by `x` or `highest_bid` and it will be a simple math question. Furthermore, you haven't used SQL in your answer either :)

Comment: @Mosty you do have a point. I didn't feel a need to provide source, and i'm newer to SQL and didn't want to speak incorrectly. If you think this question needs to be disposed of, flag it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percent increase from item_reserve to highest_bid would be:

```
( (highest_bid / item_reserve) - 1 ) * 100.
```

For example, if they are 100 and 110, respectively, you have a

```
((110/100)-1)*100 = (1.1 - 1) * 100 = a 10% increase.
```